# Install rust on openjdk docker image

Tags: java, docker, selenium, testing, rust

I'm trying to write a dockerfile to run a rust test suite that requires a jar to be running on a separate port. I've downloaded the jar into the project and would like to start with the openjdk docker image and download rust as well. That way I can use the java command to run the jar then cargo to run the tests.

```
# Start with java
FROM openjdk:latest

# Add rust
RUN <one line command to download rust>

# Install production dependencies and build a release artifact.
RUN cargo build --release

# Start chromedriver, geckodriver, and selenium standalone binary
RUN ./thirtyfour/tests/binaries_and_jars/chromedriver
RUN ./thirtyfour/tests/binaries_and_jars/geckodriver
RUN java -jar ./thirtyfour/tests/binaries_and_jars/selenium.jar standalone --port 1234

# Run the tests
RUN cargo test
```

I was hoping to download rust using the curl command provided on the website, passing all the options as cli arguments, but I still get the prompt. Running

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- --default-toolchain stable --default-host x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --profile default
```

still produces the confirmation prompt.

I'm open to any solution here, including

1. A one-line command to install rust
2. Starting from the rust image + a one-line command to install java.

Comment: The setup you're describing – with a second program, on a different port, written in a different language – sounds like it'd be better approach with a second container with a completely independent image.  Do you have a specific need for these to actually be in the same container/image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the confirmation prompt by adding the `-y` argument. This can be found in the help page of installer script.

```
The installer for rustup

USAGE:
    rustup-init [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]

FLAGS:
    -v, --verbose           Enable verbose output
    -q, --quiet             Disable progress output
    -y                      Disable confirmation prompt.
        --no-modify-path    Don't configure the PATH environment variable
    -h, --help              Prints help information
    -V, --version           Prints version information

OPTIONS:
        --default-host <default-host>              Choose a default host triple
        --default-toolchain <default-toolchain>    Choose a default toolchain to install
        --default-toolchain none                   Do not install any toolchains
        --profile [minimal|default|complete]       Choose a profile
    -c, --component <components>...                Component name to also install
    -t, --target <targets>...                      Target name to also install
```

Comment: Ah yes, the standard option for skipping the prompt that was well documented and I failed to try xD Not my proudest moment haha. Thanks for this! Actually read the --help and just kept missing it lol.